# Where is the .py code that will allow me to link python to lex?

Tags: python, boto3

Using this github link https://github.com/boto/boto3#quick-start

I'm trying to link python to luis but I can't seem to find the exact *.py* file that will serve as my template where I can apply changes.

Note: What I need is lex's engine to build a chatbot.

Thanks.

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lex-runtime.html

Comment: I have found these but what i can't find is an example explaining them or applying them, they're too complicated for a beginner.

Comment: try your best and post question if you don't understand.  The client is just an API between your recording/speech files to Amazon Lex. It is not that complicate as you imagine.

Comment: Thanks i shall, and can you guide me to any example or template application.

Comment: Maybe you should try out with  the AWS CLI first, then switch to boto3 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/getting-started.html

Comment: I figured out that what i need is post_text, however i still get error when i say response = client.post_text('hi')

Comment: Show your code and the stacktrace error.